# How to execute files which are found by find

Tags: bash, find, exec

I have some executable files under a directory tree. I want to find them and execute them the most simple way.
I've tried this so far:
`find . -perm 0775 -type f | xargs exec`
But exec is not an executable, it is a bash internal.
I could create a wrapper script which could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# exec.sh
exec $1
```

And then could run `find . -perm 0775 -type f -exec ./exec.sh {} \;`
But there's gotta be a more elegant and shorter way of doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drop the script.

```
find . -perm 0775 -type f -exec '{}' ';'
```

works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is not really suited to doing this; it is mainly meant to supply a fixed command with arguments read from standard input.

But you can call the programs directly using a simple shell loop:

```
find . -perm 0775 -type f | while read program; do
                                $program
                            done
```